# Custom RPC URL Support for EVM Mainnet?

Tags: mainnet, safe

We are currently developing a new EVM-based mainnet and we are interested to know if Safe Wallet supports custom RPC URL functionality. Could you please let us know if it is possible to configure and use a custom RPC URL with Safe Wallet?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.